# Put a string in a array, separated by special char

Tags: php, arrays, string

In php i would like to put a string like that :

```
*1\t1\tSomejehjdbsj\t7\t10\t5\t10\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t--:--\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t00:00:00\t0\t1\t0\t0\t1f7ef741\t15:42\t99\t1026\t1\t--:--\tShowVault\t0\t1f7ef74187664f03876538511f30a5af\tSomejehjdbsj\t0\t0\t00000000000000000000000000000000\t\t00000000000000000000000000000000\t00000000000000000000000000000000\t0\t0\tNC-Series\t1\t12\tSCOPE\t16\t-1\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t\t0\t\t\n"]}*
```

But each `\t` split my string and its differents values.
And the `\n` is another "row" of that kind of stuff.
I need those values so i thinks i could put it in an array, But i don't know how to do that.
thanks!

Comment: do you want to split a string by either `\t` OR `\n` into a single array?

Comment: in fact both, In the \n spliter i've got other \t spliter

Comment: imagine a box in a box

Comment: show the approximate expected result, at least a part of them

Comment: if i understand what you are saying, first explode on \n into array, then loop thru that array and explode each line by \t http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I see only one `\n` within your string, at the very end. No reason to split by `\n` in such example

Comment: in fact its juste a exemple but imagine the same string copy and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$testString = 'AAA\tBBB\nCCC\tDDD';

$result = explode('\\t', $testString);
foreach ($result as $key => $current) {
    if (strpos($current, '\\n')) {
        $result[$key] = explode('\\n', $current);    
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

See it in action here: https://3v4l.org/92ttB